# Inserting models at arbitrary positions in a rails 4 association collection

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a typical `has_many` relation between two models, let's say `Order` and `Item`.

Also, I am using nested attributes like so:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

When putting together a nested **edit** order form, I want to be able to build new items (where an item has a name and a quantity) and insert them at arbitrary positions within the previously saved list of items.

Suppose I have a sorted array of strings listing `all_possible_item_names` a customer can specify a quantity for.

Until rails 3.2.13, `@order.items` was a simple array, and I could use ruby's own `Array#insert` method to insert new items wherever I wanted:

```
# after loading the original order, this code will build additional items
# and insert them in the nested edit order form with a default qty of 0
all_possible_item_names.each_with_index do |name, pos|
  unless @order.items.find { |i| i.name == name }
    @order.items.insert pos, Item.new(name: name, qty: 0)
  end
end
```

In rails 4, on the other hand, `@order.items` is a `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, and `insert` has a different meaning.

How can I accomplish in rails 4 what I used to be able to do in rails 3?

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into array then insert

```
 @order.items.to_a.insert pos, Item.new(name: name, qty: 0)
```